# Correct format when talking about money $$

Tags: formatting, essay

I'm writing a formal research paper (Highschool)

I have lots of statistics involving money (In fact, my whole essay is about the economy).

So a question arises about the format of writing money.

Would it be:

**The company spent $4.5 billion dollars.**

or simply

**The company spent $4.5 billion.**

Do I need to include the "dollars" at the end? Which one is more customary?

Thank you

Comment: $ and dollars are equal, hence you only need one, but the symbol would be easier for someone who is reading the paper.

Answer (score 6):

Go with the second option.  The first is redundant - you've got $ as a symbol AND as a word.

Comment: yes, it reads "Four point five billion dollars dollars."

Comment: Also an option is "four point five billion dollars" or "4.5 billion dollars" or "4,500,000 dollars."  As a sidenote, at least in MLA format any number under 1,000 is written out using words and only over 1,000 is written in digits.  Of course if this is a mathematical or scientific paper different rules apply.

Comment: @justkt $4.5 billion would be $4,500,000,000 =P Yours says $4.5 million.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the context, you might wish to consider specifying which currency it is, eg

> The company spent $4.5 billion (USD)

As there are many different dollars, and they all use the same $ symbol.

If that is the only currency used within the paper then you could state that the currency is US dollars at the start rather than for every amount.